# Is there anything to limit mongodb cpu usage?

Tags: mongodb, resources, cpu-usage, php-mongodb

I have got mongo db using only one collection and consuming average cpu usage of 100%, how can I limit its resources?

**note:** I have got core 2 quad processor, running on centos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely are missing indexes; make sure you review the indexing section of the [PHP tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php).

Comment: Does the index set on the collection field like SQL, or for every entry ?

Comment: That solved the problem from 100% average to 3% average, thanks so much